# How to configure cron to run at multiple random intervals?

Tags: cron

I'm working on a new project and I would like to setup a cron to run every 6-8 hours at a random minute. Any suggestions on the best way to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should take a look at https://crontab.guru/

Comment: @gogaz thanks for the suggestion. I took a look, but I don't see a way to randomize the minute so the script only executes once every 8th hour?

Answer (score 0):

Let's run the cron every 6 hours:

`0 */6 * * * /path/to/script.sh`

Now, in your bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
maxdelay=$((2*60)) # 2 hours converted to minutes
delay=$(($RANDOM%maxdelay)) # a random delay
(sleep $((delay*60)); /path/to/script.sh) & # background a subshell to wait, then run the script
```

You can also use anacron for `RANDOM_DELAY` feature.